# Sql code for distinct fields

Tags: sql, db2

I was wondering if anyone can help me with this query.

I have two tables that I join together (`DDS2ENVR.QBO AND KCA0001.ORTS`)

THE `QBO` Table has a field labeled NIIN AND RIC. THE `KCA0001.ORTS` table has a field named SERVICE and OWN_RIC.

I Join the tables by `QBO.RIC` and `ORTS.OWN_RIC`. My dilemma is that under the NIIN field multiple rows can be identical but have different values for RIC.

Example:

```
NIIN         RIC
123455        A
122222        B
123456        C
122222        A
```

I want to query a distinct count for `NIINS` that separates by the different service where it does not overlap. So example `NIIN` should only find distinct values only associated with A where the same `NIIN` is not found in B,C,D etc.

```
SELECT D.SERVICE, COUNT(C.NIIN)
FROM DDS2ENVR.QBO C 
JOIN KCA0001.ORTS D ON D.OWN_RIC = C.RIC
WHERE C.SITE_ID = ('HEAA')
GROUP BY D.SERVICE
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT C.NIIN) > 1
```

Please ask questions if this does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Not Exists`

```
SELECT D.SERVICE, COUNT(C.NIIN)
FROM DDS2ENVR.QBO C 
JOIN KCA0001.ORTS D ON D.OWN_RIC = C.RIC
WHERE C.SITE_ID = ('HEAA')
      and NOT EXISTS (Select 1 from DDS2ENVR.QBO C1 where C1.NIIN = C.NIIN and C1.RIC <> C.RIC)
GROUP BY D.SERVICE
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT C.NIIN) > 1
```

Also if the table `DDS2ENVR.QBO` doesn't contain duplicates and your dbms supports `CTE`

```
With cte as
(Select NIIN from DDS2ENVR.QBO group by NIIN having count(*) = 1)
SELECT D.SERVICE, COUNT(C.NIIN)
FROM DDS2ENVR.QBO C 
JOIN KCA0001.ORTS D ON D.OWN_RIC = C.RIC
WHERE C.SITE_ID = ('HEAA')
      and C.NIIN in (Select * from cte)    
GROUP BY D.SERVICE
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT C.NIIN) > 1
```

Comment: I believe this worked for me. However i forgot to mention another criteria. for RIC, NIIN can not overlap for certain RICS but it can for others. Example A can not overlap B C D but it can overlap with E, F, G.

Comment: Well, you can't keep on changing your question, you should ask another question for that. Also the criteria you mentioned makes no sense. How would one know the 'certain' RICS

Comment: My apologies for changing the question. I will try to word this as best as i can. The NIIN field (In the DDS2ENVR.QBO table) can have rows with the same value but different values in the RIC field. NIINS should not be counted if certain RICS share the same NIIN value. Example RIC A AND RIC B can have the same NIIN Value but it should not be counted but RIC A and RIC E can have the same NIIN and should be counted. Should i ask another question? Again i apologize for the confusion.

Comment: I'll suggest you do ask another question. The logic behind the difference between B and E for A is not clear to me

Comment: I will go ahead and ask another question. Thank you for your help.